# Exercise on Sylow's theorems

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

First I have to compute the number of subgroup of order $3$ and $5$ of $S_5$ (the symmetric group of five elements) and $A_5$ (the alternant group of five elements) and I know that Sylow's theorems can help me in doing this however I am not very sure on how to proceed in the actual computations.

Then I have to explicitly build the subgroups of order $3$ and here I really don't know how to do this so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HInt. You don't need Sylow theory for this. Just count the number of elements of order $3$ (or $5$) and think about how they fit into subgroups. Cycle notation for permutations will help. That will also "build them" for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The elements of order $\;3\;$ are the $\;3,\,-$ cycles **only**...and the same is true for $\;5\;$ . How many of these are there in $\;S_5\;$ , and how many of these belong to the same subgroup?

Of course, you can also use Sylow's Theorems to help you calculate the number of subgroups in each case.

Comment: (I'm curious, why the weird spacing?)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I suffer from an acute case of literary claustrophobia.